# h2o Driverless AI Install on GCP

Tags: h2o

I'm installing H20 Driverless AI on Google Cloud Platform on Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm following these instructions: 
http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/UsingDriverlessAI.pdf

It goes well - or so I think - until step 15, the last one.

I type the following

```
docker run \
> --rm \
> -u `id -u`:`id -g` \
> -p 12345:12345 \
> -p 9090:9090 \
> -v `pwd`/data:/data \
> -v `pwd`/log:/log \
> -v `pwd`/license:/license \
> -v `pwd`/tmp:/tmp \
> opsh2oai/h2oai-runtime
```

And get:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/log/20180111-180304': Permission denied
```

20180111-180304 corresponds to the timestamp of the action.

When ls, here is the list of the files and folders present on the virtual machine:

```
data  demo  driverless-ai-docker-runtime-rel-1.0.5.gz  install.sh  jupyter  license  log  scripts  tmp
```

I'd be keen to hear if you've encountered a similar error or understand what I am doing wrong.

I've also tried `sudo docker run \`; similar outcome

Answer (score 0):

In this case the command presented is suggesting you want to mount

the docker host /log into the docker containers /log

The /log folder in question must have the privileges to write
of the user who launched the docker run command.

Or launch the container with sudo